# Traversing a deep data structure & deleting object

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I have a function to traverse a complex deep HashMap structure. My problem is that when I find the desired node, and do any action on it, such as deleting it, I'm not actually doing any action on the data structure, but instead I'm operating on a copy of the data structure. I'd think a pointer such as in C++ would solve my problem, so how can I do this in Java?

The code:

```
private HashMap parentNode = null;
// a complex JSON string of arrays / objects, won't list for brevity
private String jsonString = ...
// parses JSON string into HashMaps for objects and Object[ ]s for arrays
private HashMap arr = (HashMap)JSON.parse(jsonString);
// find the node with an id of 27
HashMap parent = findNode(arr, "27");
// Print arr before modifying node
System.out.println(arr);
// modify parent in some way
parent = null;    
// Print arr after modifying node
System.out.println(arr);

public HashMap findNode(HashMap map, String id) {
    parentNode = null;
    findNodeRecursive(map, id);
    return parentNode;
}

public void findNodeRecursive(HashMap map, String id) {
    for(Object entry : map.entrySet()){
        Object value = ((Map.Entry)entry).getValue();
        if((value instanceof String) && ((String)value).equals(id))
            parentNode = map;
        else if(value instanceof HashMap)
            findNodeRecursive((HashMap)value,id);
        else if(value instanceof Object[])
            for(int i=0; i<((Object[])value).length; i++)
                findNodeRecursive( (HashMap)(((Object[])value)[i]) ,id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not operating on a copy in general. If you've got a specific piece of code that's not behaving as you expect, it would help if you posted it here.

Comment: You should really post the entire structure of your code (not including the json string), as what you've posted is not valid. Where are you doing anything with the search result and why do you think its a copy?

Comment: @andrew I updated the code, I just set the search result node to null. I print the arr tree before and after this update, and its identical, with the parent node still present.

Comment: Maybe I need to not simply set the object to null, but actually use the HashMap api calls and set( ) it to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the node you want (`parent`), change your

```
parent = null;
```

to

```
arr.remove(parent);
```

Setting it to `null` does not delete anything, simply changes the reference that once was pointing to the node, back to null. To delete, you need to do it explicitly by using the [HashMap.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method